# Javascript function inside if statement still runs even though condition is not met

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make that when a user scroll till a certain point (1250px from the top), the script will run a function "just ONCE", then when the user scroll more till another 1250px from the point before (2500px from the top), the script will run the function again ONCE.

However, my script keeps running the function after 1250 px, which I already added another 1250 to var current_post, so at this point, var current_post should be 2500, and if the var offset is at 1600, the function should not run, but it is keep running.

Javascript

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var offset = $(window).scrollTop();
    var current_pos = 1250;

    if(offset > current_pos) {
        current_pos += 1250;
        //do some function
   }
});
```

Please help me spot my mistake and correct my understanding of this.. Thx in advance.

Comment: You reset the variable back to 1250 every time so adding to it later won't have any practical effect.

Comment: *"Javascript function inside if statement still runs even though condition is not met"* No, it doesn't. JavaScript isn't broken.

Comment: oh okay, so stupid of me... Thank you so much for that simple solution.. put it as answer and I will gladly accept it as answer..

Comment: @Charas: I would suggest your change the title to be more relevant to the question, as it stands it's an incorrect statement suggesting that there is a problem with how javascript evaluates conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that each time the event is being fired, you are setting the `current_pos` back to 1250. So you never get to use the updated value.

Try setting the `current_pos` variable outside of the event handler, so it doesn't get re-assigned to 1250 with each event.

```
var current_pos = 1250;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var offset = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(offset > current_pos) {
        current_pos += 1250;
        //do some function
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Place `var current_pos=1250` outside your `scroll` event like on below:

```
var current_pos = 1250; //paste it here

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var offset = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(offset > current_pos) {
        current_pos += 1250;
        //do some function
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put out the variable:

```
var current_pos = 1250;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var offset = $(window).scrollTop();

    console.log(offset);
    if(offset > current_pos) {
       current_pos += 1250;
        //do some function
        console.log(current_pos);
     }
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sq32f7h8/

Comment: Yes, I just realised it after posting this question, so stupid of me, so sorry, thank you so much..